# Python 3, How to set Visual Studio C++ 2015 compiler?

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, pycrypto

I have installed `Python 3.6 64bit` version for my Windows 10 PC. I also have `Visual Studio 2015` which has these folders:
[image: Visual studio 2015 folder]

Some python libs, like `pycrypto` requires C++ compilation in order to be installed.

Now when I try to install `pycrypto` it throws me that kind of error:

```
warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Command "d:\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\MrD\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-rzwqmfpp\\pycrypto\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'ope
n', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\MrD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-rzm9kzme-record\insta
ll-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\MrD\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-rzwqmfpp\pycrypto\
```

How to make `python3` to be able to use my VS 2015 C++ compiler?

**========= UPDATE ============**

I was able to install Common C++ tools for Visual Studio. Now my `VC` folder looks like this:
[image: after installation]

Now when I try to install my `pycrypto` I get these errors:

```
winrand.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(26): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'intmax_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'rem'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(27): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(28): error C2059: syntax error: '}'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(30): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'imaxdiv_t'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(30): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(40): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Number'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Number'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(41): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(42): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(45): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier '_Numerator'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '_Numerator'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: ';'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(46): error C2059: syntax error: ','
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(48): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(50): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(56): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(63): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(69): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(76): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(82): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(89): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\inttypes.h(95): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '__cdecl'
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

It says that it has **syntax errors**?!! Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found solution for my own question. More like I have found the way how to **evade** this problem.

The method is to install `pycryptodome` instead of `pycrypto`. According to their description it is fully compatible with `pycrypto` and it installed without any conflicts.